# (Qt SDK) MySQL Brainstorm -.-

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qtsql

I created a database. Everything seems in order to start filling it up, but every timei try to debug my project it throws this error into my face:

> "error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtSql': No such file or
>   directory"

I don't understand why I get it. In every projects I do the same, and it works just perfectly.

I include:

`#include <QtSql>`

Then I create the Database like this:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setPort(3306);
db.setDatabaseName("nevekdb");
db.setUserName("root"); 
db.setPassword("");
```

And then i try getting it's content this way:

```
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(4);
        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(selectQuery.size());
        QStringList fl;
        fejlecek << "ID" << "Name" << "Password" << "Appartment Floor";
        ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(fl);
        int i=0;
        while (selectQuery.next()) 
        {
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,0,new QTableWidgetItem(selectQuery.value(0).toString()));
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,1,new QTableWidgetItem(selectQuery.value(1).toString()));
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,2,new QTableWidgetItem(selectQuery.value(2).toString()));
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,3,new      QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(selectQuery.value(3).toInt())));
QTableWidgetItem(selectQuery.value(3).toString()));               
            i++;
```

Comment: What OS are you on? If Linux, did you install the correct package for qt+sql? Also, on Windows, I think to enable mysql driver for qt is tricky.

Comment: Turns out i didn't add that line saed wrote. man. i feel miserable right now >.< anyhow, thank you for your reply, and have a wonderful day :D

Comment: Fix your title so that it describes your question, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add this line in your .pro file:

```
QT+= sql
```

Comment: Thank you :*  I don't know how it could have slipped my mind :D

Comment: aerm, how can i change my question to [ANSWERED]?

Comment: @RubenHubert ~> :D You're very welcome. Just click the TICK beside my answer ! :D